# Java: How to Map Many To Many relationship in spring boot

Tags: java, sql, spring, many-to-many, entity-relationship

I have two entities `Venue` and `Sports` and they have`ManyToMany`
relationships, First I mapped this relation on Venue side and now I want to get Sports with the venue so I want to put relation on both sides like `OneToMnay` and `ManyToOne` relationship in the following entity but it gives me the following error

Can somebody figure out the issue?

**Sport.class**

```
@Entity
public class Sport implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

private String name;

@OneToOne(mappedBy="sport",targetEntity=SportPhoto.class)
private SportPhoto sportPhoto;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="sport",targetEntity=Session.class)
private List<Session> session;
//it gives an error on adding these lines
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "sport", fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
private Set<Venue> venues;
// getters and setters 
}
```

**Venue.class**

```
@Entity
public class Venue {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private long id;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String name;

private int maxCapacity;

private Double size;

private String mapName;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ContractType contractType;

@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private ContractDuration contractDuration;

private String ContractDetails;

@Column(nullable=false)
private String address;

private String venueContactNumber;

@JsonDeserialize(using = CustomDateDeserializer.class)
@JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateSerializer.class)
private Date contractExpireDate;

private Boolean enabled=true;

private Double latitude;

private Double longitude;

@ManyToMany
private Set<Sport> sport;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="venue",targetEntity=VenuePhoto.class)
private List <VenuePhoto> venuePhotos;

@OneToMany(mappedBy="venue",targetEntity=Session.class)
private List <Session> sessions;
// getters and setters
 }
```

**Error**

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Unable to execute schema management to JDBC target [alter table venue_sport add constraint FKtoqu08gw87dp96xwtvn1ejl27 foreign key (venues_id) references venue (id)]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.TargetDatabaseImpl.accept(TargetDatabaseImpl.java:59) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:431) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:420) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.applyForeignKeys(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:386) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigrationToTargets(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:214) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaMigratorImpl.doMigration(SchemaMigratorImpl.java:60) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:134) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate.execute(SchemaUpdate.java:101) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:472) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:444) ~[hibernate-core-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:879) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-5.0.12.Final.jar:5.0.12.Final]
    ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`mysportsacademy`.`#sql-10fc_22b`, CONSTRAINT `FKtoqu08gw87dp96xwtvn1ejl27` FOREIGN KEY (`venues_id`) REFERENCES `venue` (`id`))
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:408) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:935) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3973) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3909) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2527) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2680) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2483) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
```